# extract text between patterns - unix - AIX

Tags: unix, sed, aix

I want to extract text between two patterns. The command that I use doesn't work on AIX but works on linux.

First, I look for the occurences of a pattern in a file and I have this

```
sed -n "/STEP 005450/p" step_100
STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017
STEP 005450 REF R-A493 STEP 000010 ( command  -s <CONTAINER> )
STEP 005450 ***FAILURE*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017 Return code : 2
STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED*** Thu Oct  5 17:33:54 CEST 2017
STEP 005450 REF R-A493 STEP 000010 ( command -s CONT1 )
STEP 005450 ***SUCCESFUL*** Thu Oct  5 17:33:55 CEST 2017
```

Secondly, I want to extract the part of the text between `STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED***` and `STEP 005450 ***FAILURE***`, but the command below doesn't work and does nothing.

```
sed -n "/STEP 005450/p" step_100 | sed -n "/STEP 005450/,/FAILURE/p"
STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017
STEP 005450 REF R-A493 STEP 000010 ( command  -s <CONTAINER> )
STEP 005450 ***FAILURE*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017 Return code : 2
STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED*** Thu Oct  5 17:33:54 CEST 2017
STEP 005450 REF R-A493 STEP 000010 ( command -s CONT1 )
STEP 005450 ***SUCCESFUL*** Thu Oct  5 17:33:55 CEST 2017
```

Normally, I should have this

```
STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017
STEP 005450 REF R-A493 STEP 000010 ( command  -s <CONTAINER> )
STEP 005450 ***FAILURE*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017 Return code : 2
```

Thanks for tour help

Comment: GNU sed does not give your desired output as you state. Probably you have a copy paste error in there

Comment: I have texted the command manually

Comment: Your question is unclear as it stands. Please adhere to the [MCVE principle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works with AIX sed, too:

```
| sed -n "/ACTIVATED/,/FAILURE/{ /ACTIVATED/{h;b}; H; /FAILURE/{g;p}; }"
```

or as one command:

```
sed -n '/STEP 005450/{ /ACTIVATED/,/FAILURE/{ /ACTIVATED/{h;b}; H; /FAILURE/{g;p}; }; }' file
```

Output:

```
STEP 005450 ***ACTIVATED*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017
STEP 005450 REF R-A493 STEP 000010 ( command  -s  )
STEP 005450 ***FAILURE*** Thu Oct  5 17:31:05 CEST 2017 Return code : 2
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/. It returns me this error:
sed: the label /ACTIVATED/,/FAILURE/{ /ACTIVATED/{h;b}; H; /FAILURE/{g;p}; } is greater than eight characters.

Comment: Too bad. It was worth a try.

Comment: try adding `;`s at every logical opportunity., i.e. `/ACTIVATED/{;h;b;};` Some seds are very particular about how they parse things and AIX is particular in sooo  many ways ;-) . Good luck.